# Django compressor throws dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-compressor

I am using django-compressor 1.4 and have been battling for many hours on finding the root cause for the following error:

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required
```

All other templates that contain the `{% compress %}` tags work correctly and the error only occurs on the one template.

The template code is:

```
{%  load compress %}

{%  compress js %}
<script src='{{ STATIC_URL }}trove/js/ZeroClipboard.js' type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'></script>
<script src='{{ STATIC_URL }}trove/js/clipboard.js' type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'></script>
<script src='{{ STATIC_URL }}trove/js/jquery.tipsy.js' type='text/javascript' charset="utf-8"></script>
{%  endcompress %}
```

I invoke the compress command through a script that calls:

```
./manage.py compress
```

The results are the same regardless if I run it through the script or running through the shell.

I have tried looking through the compressor code but I am not exactly sure what I am looking for, as I do not really know what the error means.

I have read articles on the web that say this is an issue with django but I do not have the option of upgrading django or django-compressor.

I hope someone can help me fix this issue.

Thanks,
nav

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: @Selcuk my version is 1.6.

Comment: There is a known bug with Django versions prior to 1.9.x. If you can't upgrade, try to find a workaround. See [this issue](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/706)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will see if I can get around this problem and will post the solution.

Comment: The link does seems to be discussing the same error I am having however, it is due to a different issue by the looks of it. Still have not found a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation I found out that my settings.py had an issue.

My settings.py had:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/scss', 'django_pyscss.compressor.DjangoScssFilter')
)
```

Note that there is no comma after the first tuple. The correct syntax is as follows:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/scss', 'django_pyscss.compressor.DjangoScssFilter'),
)
```

Adding the comma made the error disappear and the files got compressed as expected.

Without that comma, Python reads the outer parentheses as grouping parentheses instead of as a tuple. This situation only arises when there is one item in the tuple. To avoid this situation, some folks prefer to use lists instead of tuples:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = [
    ('text/scss', 'django_pyscss.compressor.DjangoScssFilter')
]
```

That way, `COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS` is always read as a list, and it will always be acceptable to Django.